# How to change straight quotes to curly quotes?

Tags: text, pandoc

I'd like to change "straight quotes" to “curly quotes” in my text document.

I tried using Pandoc's [`--smart`](http://pandoc.org/README.html)

```
pandoc in.txt --smart -o out.txt -t plain --no-wrap
```

This is almost perfect, except that it loses *emphasis*.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you think this is a bug in Pandoc? If so I'll report it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the output format to markdown too:

```
pandoc in.txt -S -o out.txt -f markdown -t markdown --no-wrap
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandoc has deprecated the `--smart/-S` option. Now you should use `+smart` or `-smart` [extension](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-smart) instead.

Considering that if you are *writing* Markdown, then the smart extension has the reverse effect: what would have been curly quotes comes out straight. So to convert the straight quotes to curly quotes, you could use:

```bash
pandoc --wrap=preserve -t markdown-smart -o out.txt in.txt
```

Thanks @tarleb. Compared with `--wrap=none`, `--wrap=preserve` is much better to preserve the original document. See the [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#general-writer-options).

Comment: Nice answer! Setting `--wrap` to `preserve` might give even better results.